# How to check how many documents do not exist out of a list in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What will be the query to retrieve the number of documents not found in a query

This is my Query

```
$params['body']['query']["bool"]["filter"]["terms"]["feild"] = (list);
```

I want to retrieve the documents not found from the list.

If my List has (A,B,C). i just need to know that C is not indexed. I don't Need A,B,D,E,F or all of the remaining documents in index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `must_not` clause to achieve the negation of your query as shown below:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "field": [
                "value-1", "value-2" 
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this returns all the documents,

Comment: i need , if the list had A,B,C and only if C not found, i should get C and not 1000 documents

Answer (score 0):

`must_not with aggregation` will give more details about that field values which you are not expecting :-

```
{
    "_source":false,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {"term": {"aFieldName": "aFieldValue"}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "byLocation": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "aFieldName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```